# Troubles with polymorphic overrides in c#

Tags: c#, directx, polymorphism

I'm very new to c# and I'm practicing with polymorphism. What I want to do is have a device be one of 3 class types (Joystick, Mouse or Keyboard). I figure the best approach is to use a class and virtual. Having troubles with the layout here?

```
namespace HID
{
    public class HIDControl
    {
.
.
.
    class agnosticDevice
    {
        private Joystick jDevice;
        private Mouse jMouse;
        private Keyboard jKeyboard;
        public string type;

        public virtual void device()// no way to return different types?
        {
            //if type is mouse return jMouse...ect?
        }
    }
.
.
.
    }
}
```

Just not understanding how to do this right or maybe I'm way off. can anyone help?

Further info, I'm using DX here and maybe there is provision for this but I dont see how. Basically in my HIDControl class I set up the DX and create a device based on user input. This input could later change and I need to changed my device. All of the devices for the most part use the same functions. As a matter a fact everything can be treated as a Joystick. Though for some advanced function I need the type changed. I know I could do class level polymorphism but so much of the classes would be redundant.

The other immediate solution is just make 3 devices in my class but if I do this I need 3 if statements for every use and that is just ugly.

**[ updated code to comment on the comments and suggestions ]**

I think I'm getting close here but when I create my device its not inheriting the members right. Here is what I have so far

```
public abstract class AgnosticDevice
    {
        public abstract void SomeDeviceOperation();
    }

    public class vJoystick : AgnosticDevice, Joystick
    {
        public vJoystick( DirectInput di, Guid g){}
        public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
        {
            /* Joystick operation */
        }
    }

    public class vMouse : AgnosticDevice, Mouse
    {
        public vMouse( DirectInput di ){}
        public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
        {
            /* Mouse operation */
        }
    }

    public class vKeyboard : AgnosticDevice, Keyboard
    {
        public vKeyboard( DirectInput di , Guid g){}
        public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
        {
            /* Keyboard operation */
        }
    }

    public class DeviceFactory
    {
        public static AgnosticDevice Create( string type, DirectInput di, Guid g )
        {
            if ( type == "Mouse" )
            {
                return new vMouse( di);
            }
            if ( type == "Joystick" )
            {
                return new vJoystick( di, g);
            }
            if ( type == "Keyboard" )
            {
                return new vKeyboard( di, g);
            }
            return new vJoystick( di, g );//defult
        }
    }
```

then I do

```
AgnosticDevice device = (vJoystick)DeviceFactory.Create( type, directInput, deviceGuid );
```

but device.( some DX function ) is not available.

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is an interface.  Something that defines the common functionality between these various input devices.  You can then have each of these classes implement that interface to perform those various actions in whatever specific manor they need to.

Comment: ah yes I recall that term used in c#, thx. I'll do some research on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might give you an idea:

Create an interface or an abstract class and define the functionality that will be shared between all your "devices":

```
public abstract class AgnosticDevice
{
    // methods ...
    public virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // something
    }
}
```

Then use it for your more specific devices:

```
public class Joystick : AgnosticDevice
{
    // perhaps overwrite DoStuff here ...
}

public class Mouse : AgnosticDevice
{

}
```

Here is how you can use this (this is essentially polymorphism):

```
public class DeviceFactory
{
    public static AgnosticDevice Create(string someInput)
    {
        if (someInput == "something")
        {
            return new Mouse();
        }
        return new Joystick();
    }
}
```

In case you want to specify a behavior that each agnostic device *must* have you're better off creating an interface (it can have NO implementation), for example:

```
public interface IPluggable
{
    void Disconnect();
}
```

Then implement it in one of your "pluggable" devices:

```
public class Joystick : IPluggable
{
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        // awesome
    }
}
```

See from here on you can do magic such as:

```
// I want you to pass me a pluggable device, I don't care if it's a Joystick or a Mouse
public static void DoWork(IPluggable pluggableDevice)
{
    try
    {
        // something will go wrong !
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);

        // all pluggable devices can disconnect, I don't care what you've passed as an argument!
        pluggableDevice.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

This is how you can use that:

```
public void Test()
{
    DoWork(new Joystick());
    DoWork(new Mouse());

    // you can do some tests by throwing in a fake device
    // to simulate behaviors that you expect
    DoWork(new FakeDevice());
}
```

Comment: this solution is also very helpful for me but like the one below I still fail to see how to get the actual DX device ? Looking at your 3rd code block you say "return new Mouse();" this returns a new class public class Mouse : AgnosticDevice but how would I have the new Mouse class return the dx Mouse?

Comment: @SeanGreen As far as I understood you need to return different devices depending on the user input, one way to do that is to define a common abstract term of what a device *is* and return that, depending on the type it is it will behave in different ways. I hope I'm making sense here, also since I suspect that I'm probably misunderstanding your requirements, perhaps you can give us more details (sort of "a bigger picture") on your problem.

Comment: I'm sure you make sense, its me that I worry about ;) Ok I think I follow you. I could explain myself so much better if I could put code in here. Mouse is a dirrectX class so my new mouse class ( AFAIK ) can not have the same name. And I think, it need to inherit the DX mouse class. like: public class vMouse : AgnosticDevice, Mouse

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is composition, not polymorphism. You can achieve polymorphism by having one abstract `Device` class and three specialization:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public abstract void SomeDeviceOperation();
}

public class Joystick : Device
{
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Joystick operation */
    }
}

public class Mouse : Device
{
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Mouse operation */
    }
}

public class Keyboard : Device
{
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Keyboard operation */
    }
}
```

You can then assign any class subclassing `Device` to a `Device` typed variable, argument, parameter, etc.. For example:

```
public void DoOperationOnDevice(Device d)
{
    d.SomeDeviceOperation();
}

Device d = new Joystick();
d.SomeDeviceOperation();
DoOperationOnDevice(new Keyboard());
d = new Mouse();
```

Comment: The base class is providing no implementations whatsoever.  You're not really gaining anything, and you are losing something, by using inheritance here, over simply an interface.

Comment: @Servy That is true, but this is also a very simple and contrived example. Device could have implementation details shared across subclassing type and it would be useful to have inheritance. If you only have one method and nothing else, then yes, an Interface would be more appropriate.

Comment: Regardless of how many methods that you have, I don't see it being the case for having a base class for common behavior.  These seem very much like concepts that are going to have an entirely different implementation, but with a common API.  Interfaces can certainly have more than just one method.

Comment: @Servy Of course. But take the example of the `Stream` class. Some logic are shared across different types of stream and some implementation details are left to the sublcassing type. Now, this might not be the case in this poster's example, but we don't know what is the `Device` class used for in the bigger picture. All in all, there are benefits and cases for both ways (interface vs class inheritance).

Comment: However, as a rule, you should favor composition over inheritance.  Inheritance is something you shouldn't be looking to first, in most situations.  It's something that you should do if there's compelling reasons to use it over the alternatives, which I simply see no evidence of.

Comment: Whether the best practices or not I like this concept the best and its very easy to follow. Going to start here but I need to ask, your example classes have the same name as the DX classes but I dont see this working as overrides so I'm wondering if that not what you meant. Should "public class Joystick : Device" be "public class vJoystick : Device" or something?

Comment: It depends... if they aren't in the same namespace, there shouldn't be naming collision issue. If you use both within the same code file (and import both namespace), you would need to use the fully qualified name of both classes (the DX and your own) or create Aliases.